# Docker Windows Installation Failed / Library not registered [Windows 10 Pro]

Tags: docker, windows-10

I am trying to install Docker for Windows 10 Pro. I have downloaded the `Docker Desktop Installer.exe` and when I run it with Administrator role I got the follwing error when it starts the installation, just after downloading and unpackaging the files.

Installation failed

```
Library not registered.
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoMachineInit()
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, String identityValue)
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue)
 at CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction.<DoAsync>b__33_0()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<HandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<ProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext(
```

I have changed my Windows user Group to Administrators and I also updated Windows 10.

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

Comment: Try disabling Windows Defender. There have been reports of it interfering with Docker installations.